# Why not run android emulator on ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am new in android studio on Ubuntu system.

After created a new project in android studio, I run it on a emulator using x86 image.
 Then a issue "Your CPU does not support required features(VT-x or SVM)" appeared.

To fix the issue I used another emulator using ARM system image.
Then when I run the project, android emulator appeared for just moment and then disappeared. 
After that the emulator no appeared.
That is MAIN PROBLEM.
I can't understand that situation.

My ubuntu system run on Virtual Box.

Android studio version is 2.3.1

Comment: Try export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 before you start Android Studio